# How do I create a Excel ComboChart (clustered bar, line) with Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts, excel-charts

For the purpose of sales department I have a query that tracks previous price points and calculates margins.  I would like to export this info to Excel to create a combo chart to make the information more visual.  I've found some sample code on another site, but it doesn't quite do everything I need.  I've used the macro recorder to come up with my desire code, but it uses different methods than my sample code.  Can anyone help me to combine the following codes to come up with Combo Charts via VBA?

```
'sample code below

Private Sub Command201_Click()
Option Compare Database
Private Const conQuery = "qryTopTenProducts"
Private Const conSheetName = "Top 10 Products"

Private Sub Command201_Click()

 Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    
 ' Excel object variables
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim xlChart As Excel.Chart
    
 Dim i As Integer
    
 On Error GoTo HandleErr
    
 ' Create Excel Application object.
 Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    
 ' Create a new workbook.
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    
 ' Get rid of all but one worksheet.
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
 For i = xlBook.Worksheets.Count To 2 Step -1
     xlBook.Worksheets(i).Delete
 Next i
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    
 ' Capture reference to first worksheet.
 Set xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet
    
 ' Change the worksheet name.
 xlSheet.Name = conSheetName
    
 ' Create recordset.
 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
 rst.OPEN _
  Source:=conQuery, _
  ActiveConnection:=CurrentProject.Connection
    
 With xlSheet
     ' Copy field names to Excel.
     ' Bold the column headings.
     With .Cells(1, 1)
         .Value = rst.Fields(0).Name
         .Font.Bold = True
     End With
     With .Cells(1, 2)
         .Value = rst.Fields(1).Name
         .Font.Bold = True
     End With
    
     ' Copy all the data from the recordset
     ' into the spreadsheet.
     .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
     
     ' Format the data.
     .Columns(1).AutoFit
     With .Columns(2)
         .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
         .AutoFit
     End With
 End With
    
 ' Create the chart.
 Set xlChart = xlApp.Charts.Add
 With xlChart
     .ChartType = xlComboColumnClusteredLine
     .SetSourceData xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
     .PlotBy = xlColumns
     .Location _
      Where:=xlLocationAsObject, _
      Name:=conSheetName
 End With
  ' Setting the location loses the reference, so you
 ' must retrieve a new reference to the chart.
 With xlBook.ActiveChart
     .HasTitle = True
     .HasLegend = False
     With .ChartTitle
         .Characters.Text = conSheetName & " Chart"
         .Font.Size = 16
         .Shadow = True
         .Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
     End With
     With .ChartGroups(1)
         .GapWidth = 20
         .VaryByCategories = True
     End With
     .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8
     .Axes(xlCategoryScale).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8
  End With
    
 ' Display the Excel chart.
 xlApp.Visible = True

ExitHere:
On Error Resume Next
' Clean up.
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

HandleErr:
MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description, , "Error in CreateExcelChart"
Resume ExitHere

End Sub
```

'macro recorded code

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'PART TARGET'!$A$1:$E$5")
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 1
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlLine 
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 1
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).ChartType = xlLine
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).AxisGroup = 1
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 2
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
```

Comment: `Option Compare Database` belongs in module header, not within procedure. Edit question to show sample data as text table. What happens if you insert the macro recorded code into procedure? Remove `ActiveChart`. Probably won't need the `Select` line.

Comment: I am attempting code in Access VBA. Right off get error on `xlComboColumnClusteredLine` as well as `FullSeriesCollection`. `xlComboColumnClustered` does not appear to be in Access VBA Excel library. This could be quite a challenge. Maybe should code in an Excel file to pull data and build chart.

Answer (score 1):

The problem breaks into two parts.  Exporting the data to Excel and then having Excel create a Combo Chart.  If you are creating the Excel file you can use Access's Export Data Wizard to create a saved export of almost anything in access.  Then its a simple call to:

```
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-MyTabletoExcel"
```

If you already have an Excel File with a macro for creating the chart from where the data goes then you can create the chart by simply calling the macro from Access

```
runExcelMacro "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\test2.xlsm", "CreateComboChart"

Public Sub runExcelMacro(wkbookPath, macroName)
'adapted from https://access-excel.tips/run-excel-macro-from-access-vba/
    Dim XL As Object
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With XL
    .Visible = False
      .displayalerts = False
      .Workbooks.Open wkbookPath
      .Run macroName
      .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
      .Quit
    End With
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```

But if you have to create the Excel file it will not have a Macro yet so it is best to create that macro in Excel then translate it to Access vba:

```
Sub CreateComboChart()
' CreateComboChart Macro
    Range("B1:D7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Table4!$B$1:$D$7")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 1
End Sub
```

became:

```
Public Sub CreateComboChartinExcel()
 'Required: Tools > Refences: Add reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim xlChart As Excel.Chart
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\test.xlsm")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet
    
    xlSheet.Range("B1:D7").Select
    xlSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    Set xlChart = xlBook.ActiveChart
    
    xlChart.SetSourceData Source:=xlSheet.Range("B1:D7")
    xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
   xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
    xlChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 1
    xlBook.Save 'surprisingly important
    xlBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Finally, the Access Export Wizard neither lets you append the exported data to the Excel file or lets you see the VBA.  So if you want to paste to an Excel file you have to either use Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet or loop through the Access tables and copy and paste to excel.  I show Docmd:

```
Public Sub TransferTable()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myTable", "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\test.xlsx"

End Sub
```